# Render pdf from weblink in shiny

Tags: r, pdf, url, shiny

I would like to display a pdf, that is available on the web and can change, directly on my shiny app. I have tried the following:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      # Inputs excluded for brevity
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("R",
                 tags$iframe(style="height:900px; width:100%; scrolling=yes", 
                             src="https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf")
      )
    )
  )
)
)



server <- function(input, output) {

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, the pdf do not display properly. Any idea to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It is working. But Iframe doesn't work well in RStudio viewer pane. Open it using an external browser instead(Chrome, Firefix, etc.).

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make it more robust and assure that it will work? e.g. I tried to download the pdf to my `www` folder first, but I failed miserably

Comment: What do you mean by robust? It will work as well as the website holding the pdf file is not down. And if you want to storeit locally, make sure to store the pdf file in `www` folder